# Spark - can "spark.deploy.spreadOut = false" give performance benefit on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

i understand "spark.deploy.spreadOut" when set to true can benefit HDFS, but for S3 can setting to false have a benefit over true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Hadoop and HDFS, it would **not** benefit you to use Spark Standalone scheduler for which that property applies. Rather, you should be running YARN, and the ResourceManager determines how executors are spread

If you are running Standalone scheduler in EC2, then setting that property *will help*, and the default is true.

In other words, where you're reading the data from is not the deciding factor here, the deploy mode for the master is

The better performance benefits would come from the number of files you're trying to read, and which formats you store the data in

Comment: would spreadout = false or = true be better in standalone scheduler?

Comment: I can't think of a reasonable scenario why you would want it to be false

Comment: In other words, since you have no control over where an executor task is started, you cannot say something to the effect of "only run executors on these really high CPU + memory machines, but leave the others alone"

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your workload.

If your S3 access is massive and is constrained by instance network IO,
setting spark.deploy.spreadOut=true will help, because it will spread it over more instances increasing the total network bandwidth available to the app.

But for the most workloads it will make no difference.

**There is also cost consideration for "spark.deploy.spreadOut" parameter.**

If your spark processing is large scale, you are likely using multiple AZs.
Default value "spark.deploy.spreadOut"= true will cause your workers to generate more network traffic on data shuffling, causing inter-AZ traffic.

**Inter-AZ traffic on AWS can get costly**

if the network traffic volume is high enough, you might want to cluster apps tighter by spark.deploy.spreadOut"= false, instead of spreading them because of the cost issue.